# Flutter Bad State: Stream has already been listened to

Tags: android, flutter, stream, flutter-method-channel

I am trying to use methodChannel in flutter to receive events from native Android code. But once I cancel the stream subscription I can no longer create new subscriptons even if I set the stream asBroadcastStream()

**Receiver.dart**

```
static Stream<dynamic> get accessStream {
  _stream ??= _eventChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().map<dynamic>(
    (event) {
      return MainEvent.fromMap(event);
    },
  );
  return _stream!.asBroadcastStream();
}
```

**When trying to call the function**

```
subs = Receiver.accessStream.listen((event) async {
          if (event != null) {
            events.add(event);
          }
        });

//After Some Time in Cancel Function
await subs.cancel()
```

It works for the first time but when I call the same function in app_listen.dart again. It gives the following error

```
[ +100 ms] E/flutter (32159): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Bad state: Stream has already been listened to.
[        ] E/flutter (32159): #0      _StreamController._subscribe (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:676:7)
[        ] E/flutter (32159): #1      _ControllerStream._createSubscription (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:827:19)
[        ] E/flutter (32159): #2      _StreamImpl.listen (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:473:9)
[        ] E/flutter (32159): #3      listenEvent(package:trying/util/struct/app_listen.dart:49:51)
[        ] E/flutter (32159): <asynchronous suspension>
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: I have removed the "dart-stream" tag since it's redundant. You already have [stream], which is the correct tag.

Comment: "Stream has already been listened to." mean you are NOT using a broadcast stream. This is a dart error when you use a single subscription stream and listen more than once, so I think it's a bug in your code. Since you did not provide a minimal example (a project that can be run and reproduce the bug), no one can tell what's wrong. Please try to debug your code.

Comment: @dante I have opened an issue in flutter and have provided my code there. Here is the link:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/106927#issuecomment-1172315570

Comment: @JustaPerson I know, I came here from the issue. You did not provide a runnable project, how can Flutter team reproduce the error with these files? And as I said, the error is clear, did you try to debug your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the issue by just removing the `??=` and replacing it with `=` in Receiver.dart